# Alarm Manager wont trigger

Tags: java, android

I asked a question similar to this yesterday but have changed my code a fair bit and have a different issue now.

I have a toggle button that sets an alarm manager with a pending intent that should trigger after 5 seconds. I have it on a one shot setting, so i want the message to appear once (as later I will be implementing this for a date value).

I get no errors with this code, but I cant seem to trigger my intent that then shows my toast message.

Here's how I have defined the activity of the 'DateAlarm' class in the xml:

```
     <activity
        android:name=".DateAlarm"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.flybase2.DateAlarm" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Heres my my toggle button onClick method for my toggle button with the alarm manager:

```
case (R.id.toggleButton1):

    Integer dobMonth = setDate.getMonth();
    Integer dobYear = setDate.getYear();
    Integer dobDate = setDate.getDayOfMonth();

    Date set;
    set = new Date(dobYear - 1900, dobMonth, dobDate);


    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DateAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000), pendingIntent); 


    break;
```

And my final 'DateAlarm' class that holds the action of the intent.

```
package com.example.flybase2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DateAlarm extends Activity {

Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     Toast.makeText(context, "Appointment is today", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Comment: Try changing PendingIntent.getService to PendingIntent.getActivity

Comment: @A--C thanks that seems to start the intent. Only issue now Is im getting a Null pointer exception when the class is opened on the DateAlarm class.

Comment: You haven't initialized context. In onCreate() do `context = this;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You are using `PendingIntent.getService()` instead of `PendingIntent.getActivity()` Since `DateAlarm` extends `Activity`, you want `PendingIntent.getActivity()`.
2. In `DateAlarm` your context variable is null. In onCreate() you should initialize it. Also note that since `Activity` extends `Context`, this variable isn't needed. However if you do want to use that variable do:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
context = this;
```

or

```
Context context = this; //right from the global declaration
```

Comment: Many thanks A--C. As a newish Java programmer sometimes context gets me confused. so I'm literally setting the context of the class i.e 'this' to the context variable? Is this correct?

Comment: No, you are not setting the Context of the class to `this`. `Activity` extends `Context` so an `Activity` is-a `Context`. All you're doing is setting your reference variable (which is quite a  redundant variable) to point to the current instance of DateAlarm. Have a look at [inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) and the `this` [keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Comment: Again many thanks for your time. That does make sense. I realise that my class is extending the super class Activity, and I also see what you mean about it being redundant. One last question If I may, after reading what you have written am i basically setting the context of the super class the context of dateAlarm, i.e as you say referencing it? Also ty for the Oracle article.

Comment: Context is a class. Therefore, Activity, DateAlarm, and Context are **all** Contexts - they're just less specific as you go up the chain. And since that redudant `context` variable is part of your DateAlarm class, the superclass knows nothing about that variable. When you extend a class, the superclass doesn't have to know anything about any subclasses. So there is nothing being set.